# How to call external executable file from java

Tags: java, runtime

I am new to java...

I have a problem while trying to call external executable file from java...

```
Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
Process pr = rt.exec("cmd /c terminal.exe");
```

while trying to call this getting below error..

```
Exited with error code 1
```

Comment: What happens if you open a windows command shell and enter "cmd /c terminal.exe" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure your `terminal.exe` is in the Windows path?
You can try and replace it with `notepad.exe`, for example, to see if it works.